# domino recursive search secondary Address Book not working

Tags: lotus-domino

Here is our issue.  We have a secondary address book listed in the da.nsf on our Domino web server. The original address book is based on version 6.5.4.  When we upgrade the version to 8.5.3 or 9.0.1, recursive searching stops working when looking for entries in the secondary address book.  Switch back to original version and it works.

We first tried doing an upgrade by replacing design of original address book and then tried by creating a new address book using the design of 8.5.3 and 9.0.1.  Every time we got same results, when searching for a name in a group within a group it does not find the entry.  It works with the 6.5.4 version but not with 8.5.3 or 9.0.1.  The person name is of email format (ie: someone@somewhere.com). Server version is 9.0.1 FP7 HF409.

Answer (score 0):

The DA works a little differently now. Things to check:

- Make sure the domain name in the DA document is different from the primary (Must be unique)
- Make sure your secondary address book is not a condensed Directory Catalog.

If these don't work, post some more details about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a view was modified at our end and the modification was overwritten by the new template.  Unfortunately, it wasn't documented anywhere at our end.  It is now.  Thanks to IBM for finding the issue even though they didn't have to since they don't support modifications to their templates.  For those who want to know what happened, we modified the ($ServerAccess) view to include email addresses (ie someone@somwhere.com).